# In a world with a species of Parasitic Flower, What afflictions could it cause to a living organism?

Tags: flora, diseases, species, parasites

### CW: Parasites, Sickness, Mentions of Wounds & Infection.

I’m currently working on a game and trying to decide if i want to keep this part in game whatsoever.

This species is a type of parasitic flower-like organism that infiltrates the body through open wounds, or other orifices. The way it works, Is they slowly take over the host, And feed off it from the inside out, whilst Slowly taking over the mind and body. eventually, It will leave the host to find a new one once the old host has died, or is too weak to move.

They’re able to lure prey because they have mouths, and are able to mimic sound. Their roots are thin and noodly, But spread over wide patches of ground to detect movement and/or sound above. They look sorta like a daisy, But, Y’know. With a mouth. And thorns to prevent predation.

What would be a reasonable progression of being infected by this species?

EDIT: Thank you all for the quick replies! i’m trying to more-so figure out how it would affect the human body in a physical manner. ( I know Lethargy, and likely Respiratory issues since the roots plant themselves into the lungs. )

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking how someone would go from "*Ouch, that flower stings!*" to someone having a [clear case of cephalophagy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lamVj1XaMts)? Or are you asking more specifically what symptoms would happen midway from normal to zombie-like?

Comment: In any case know that you should have some freedom in what happens, even with the horror tropes in mind (I say this because such plants would fit perfectly in an horror game... See *The Last of Us*' shroomies, actually :p). Those infections don't happen on humans in the real-world, [at most small insects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ophiocordyceps_unilateralis). And well, the compulsive horror and deep meaning of losing control of yourself as you are eaten alive by the petal demon can be more important than being true to real-world science, usually.

Comment: Not sure why you've gone for mouths as most plants already have various ways of attracting the creatures required for their reproductive purposes, but you do you!

Answer (score 3):

Stages would be best, unless you want your flower to be like a [Triffid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triffid) and roam around finding victims. But unless it's a very quick and agile plant, which isn't very realistic it needs blind people to target otherwise they'll just kill it.

With stages you have a more insidious infection mechanism, they can infect via spores or seeds. Then either rinse and repeat or infect by making the host attack another human and pass on their spores while doing so. Variations on this is the scenario in a few  books. And already in a very enjoyable (except for some weird uncalled for stuff) game called [The Last Of Us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_of_Us).

This was a fungus, but you could perhaps do the same with pollen somehow.

Comment: Let's add to the mind-controlling plants references Poison Ivy from DC Comic. Then... Mass Effect has the [Thorian](https://masseffect.fandom.com/wiki/Thorian), Resident Evil loves assimilating people with mushrooms, as far as I remember. With more fantastic and somewhat less horror vibes, the [Mushishi](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mushishi) manga offers lots of plants and animal looking spirits who control the mind of their host to an extent, in order to fulfill said spirits' goals.

Comment: @Tortliena I'm not familiar with any of those, they sound pretty cool though

Answer (score 2):

You should start by looking at the range of fungi that pull this off. From simple skin based Candida infections causing itching and discomfort to more serious things like [Valley Fever](https://www.cdc.gov/fungal/diseases/coccidioidomycosis/index.html) and our local favourite, [Cordyceps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ophiocordyceps_unilateralis) (the zombie fungus).

By your description you want to go full cordyceps on this one, from infection to taking over behahiour to benefit its own reproduction. Taking host in larger animals and laying down a root structure internally the creature would slowly lose mobility, so your plant would have to drive it to seek out a suitable environment for its next phase before it becomes totally immobile.

Being a plant, once the initial host has died you could say that your organism is now well enough grown to take root in the particularly poor local soils (standard environment for carnivorous plants) and use the remains of its formerly mobile host as a source of nutrients for as long as it lasts.

Your plant is now in its reproductive phase and looking to infect new hosts. Probably fruit eating land animals, though you could consider merely sharp barbed seeds that enter through the soft pads on passing animals' feet (much as grass seeds do to dogs).

As a rule, plants don't care about the self, the plant itself wouldn't move to a new host, it would reproduce to new hosts.

Answer (score 2):

> What would be a reasonable progression of being infected by this species?

Since the parasite feeds on the host's body, a reasonable progression would be to start from the non vital parts of the body, so that it can live longer and provide nutrition for longer time. Therefore start from partially eating muscles and fat (not the entirety of each muscle, you want the host to still be able to move around) and leave heart and brain for last.